# metodo que funciona y cuando lo llamo no funciona

Tags: java, mvc, crud

Tengo el siguiente codigo de la clase Sdao:

```
public Listado2 read() throws SQLException{ 
    con=new ConexionMysql();
    String query="SELECT ID, NUM_BUTACAS FROM sala";        
    try{
        conn=con.getConexion();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            s.setNumSala(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)));
            s.setNumButacas(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)));              
            listado.add(s);
            //System.out.println(s);//FUNCIONA incluso sin <Sala>
        }  
        rs.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JDBCUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    }finally {
        if (stmt != null) { 
            stmt.close(); 
        }
    }
    return listado;
}
```

Como podeis ver en el comentario funciona perfectamente.
Tengo otra clase Listado2

```
public class Listado2 {
private List<Sala> listado;


public Listado2() throws SQLException{
    listado=new ArrayList<>();      
    
}

public List<Sala> get(){
    return listado;
}

public void set(List<Sala> listado){
    this.listado=listado;
}

public void add(Sala e){
    listado.add(e);
}

public Sala get(int index){
    if (index >= 0 && index < listado.size()) {
        return listado.get(index);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public int size(){
    return listado.size();        
}

public void listar(){//FUNCIONA 
    for(Sala lista:listado){
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

}

Ahora lo llamo desde otra clase diagamos Controlador

```
listado=getObjSdao().read();
listado.listar();
```

En la primera de las clases me muestra el listado correctamente, sin embargo al llamarlo en este método anterior me muestra tantas filas como registros hay pero todos con los datos del último registro. No acabo de resolver el problema y lo he probado en la clase Listado2 tanto con parámetros como sin. A ver si alguien sabe algo.
Gracias de antemano. Un saludo a todos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. Sería mejor que pongas las clases completas. No se sabe a qué clase pertenece el primer bloque de código, ni qué son  los objetos `listado` y `s` en este contexto: `listado.add(s);`

Comment: En el Controlador he declarado e, inicializado en el construcctor tanto la Sala como el Listado2, ambos sin parámetros. Y en el constructor inserto como parámetro un objSdao que especifico también en el super() ya que Controlador extends ControladorPrincipal. Mi objetivo solo es obtener el listado de los registros. Al pulsar el botón debería listarme. Gracias A. Cedano por tu comentario y espero que este mi comentario te sirva.

Comment: Repito: **en el contexto no se ve lo que es `listado` ni lo que es `s`**. Tampoco vemos tu clase `Sala` para poder ayudarte mejor. Si `listado` admite objetos del tipo `Sala` y ésta tuviera un constructor que admita dos parámetros (si no los tiene lo puedes declarar), podrías llenar la lista con algo así: **`listado.add( new Sala(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)) );`** o bien creando cada vez una instancia de `Sala` y pasándoles los datos con los *setter*.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el `while`, porque al objeto `s` solo le creas una instancia y es la que agregas a la lista, por eso estas modificando el mismo objeto en memoria que a su vez es el que esta agregado en cada registro de la lista quedando con los últimos datos recuperados.

Solución: Crea una instancia nueva de `s` por cada fila que recuperes de la base de datos.

```
while(rs.next()){
   Sala s = new Sala(); // Aquí crea una instancia por cada fila.
   s.setNumSala(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)));
   s.setNumButacas(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)));              
   listado.add(s);
}
```

Comment: He puesto un comentario anterior como suplemento a mi pregunta inicial. Podrás ver que ya he creado un objeto Sala y solo pretendo obtener el listado correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como dicen mis colegas alli tenía el error. He sustituido en el método public Listado2 read(),
listado.add(s);
por
listado.add(new Sala(s.getNumSala(),s.getNumButacas()));.
No pensaba que ahí tenía el error porque la comprobación del método me resultaba correcto. Gracias.